# How to create 'other' option in SelectField in Flask WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am still kind of new to python and flask, and I have a SelectField created, but I want to have it like how websites have the 'other' option, for example if a website asks for gender, it might have the options 'male', 'female', and 'other' and when you select other you are prompted with a new TextField to type in. I don't know how to execute code on the selection in the SelectField, I only know how to do it on submit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display individual input fields or groups of input fields based on a selected value, the use of JavaScript in connection with a style sheet is necessary.

In the following example, a fieldset is displayed as soon as the "Other" option is selected. To do this, an EventListener is added to the input field. If this receives an event, the specific fieldset is selected and enabled based on the name and value of the input field. All other fieldsets with a name starting with the selectbox name are disabled.
With the same technique it is also possible to show and hide individual fields.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField, StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'your secret here'

# Options for the select box.
@unique
class Options(str, Enum):
    OPTION1 = 'Option 1'
    OPTION2 = 'Option 2'
    OPTION3 = 'Other'

# Validate input based on value and name of another field.
class RequiredIf(DataRequired):
    def __init__(self, other_field_name, other_field_value, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        self.other_field_value = other_field_value
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form[self.other_field_name]
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception(f'no field named "{self.other_field_name}" in form')
        if other_field.data == self.other_field_value:
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)

class ExampleForm(FlaskForm):
    options = SelectField('Options', choices=[e.value for e in Options])
    options_details = StringField('Details',
        validators=[
            RequiredIf('options', Options.OPTION3.value)
        ]
    )

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ExampleForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        option = form.options.data
        if option == Options.OPTION3.value:
            option = form.options_details.data
        print(option)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      /* Hide disabled fieldsets. */
      fieldset[disabled] {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form method="post">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <div>
          {{ form.options.label() }}
          {{ form.options() }}
      </div>

      <fieldset name="options-other">
        <div>
          {{ form.options_details.label() }}
          {{ form.options_details() }}
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        // Register event listener to change the visibility of the fieldset
        // based on the selected option.
        const selectElem = document.querySelector('select[name="options"]');
        selectElem.addEventListener('change', evt => {
          const selected = `${evt.target.name}-${evt.target.value.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}`;
          const selector = `fieldset[name^="${evt.target.name}-"]`;
          document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elem => {
            elem.disabled = !(elem.name && elem.name === selected);
          });
        });

        // Initialize visibility of fieldset after loading.
        const selected = `${selectElem.name}-${selectElem.value.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}`;
        const selector = `fieldset[name^="${selectElem.name}-"]`;
        document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elem => {
          elem.disabled = !(elem.name && elem.name === selected);
        });

      })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```